# denseness, connectedness and openness of a subset of $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

$X=C[0,1]$ with supnorm topology. Let $$S=\{f\in X:\int_{0}^{1} f(t)dt \ne 0\}$$

I need to know which of the following is/are true?

1. $S$ is open
2. $S$ is dense in $X$
3. $S$ is connected

for the $1$ I took $F:X\to \mathbb{R}, F(f)=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt, S=[F^{-1}(0)]^c$ so $1$ is true.

For $3$ we see that Image of $S$ under the defined continuous map is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ which is disconnected so $S$ can not be connected.

For $2$ I thought like this: I took a function $f(x)=0$, but there is no sequence of functions from $S$ which approximate $f(x)$ or converges to $f(x)$ because $f_n(x)\in S\Rightarrow\int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)\ne 0$  so their limit function will be either $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx>0 $ or $<0$

so $S$ is not dense. am I right in all cases? thanks

Comment: You are right for 1 and 3. If you are given a function with $\int f = 0$, can you perturb $f$ a little bit to form $f_\epsilon$ so that $\int f_\epsilon \neq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth pointing out that the reason your proof for 1 works is because $F$ is continuous. Your proof for 3 is good. For 2, let $f\in X\setminus S$. Given $\epsilon>0$, let $g(x)=f(x)+\frac\epsilon2$. Then
$$\int_0^1g(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)+\frac\epsilon2dx=\frac\epsilon2>0$$
so $g\in S$. Since $\|f-g\|_\infty<\epsilon$, this shows $S$ is in fact dense in $X$.